# Do not see "Classic Email Template" option in Setup

Tags: lightning, email-template, setup

I have tried to find **Classic Email Template** in Setup in my *Developer Organization*,

[image]

However I could **not** find it.
I logged in **another Dev org** and I see it.

[image]

I do not see it neither in **Lightning** nor in **Classic**

I looked into this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.classic_templates_in_lightning_considerations.htm&type=5), but could not find anything.
Does anyone have something similar recently ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383802/system-administrator-cant-access-email-templates

Comment: @Vinay Thank you, I did not see it.

Comment: Np, let me know if you see any issues : )

Comment: @Vinay Thank you, it did resolve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383802/system-administrator-cant-access-email-templates/383808#383808), Using match production licenses tool will enable Email Template and resolve the issue.